# Finding the sample size of students with the confidence level

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, sampling, confidence-interval

Here is my question:
How large a sample of students would be needed in order to estimate the population prediction mean within ±2 with 85% confidence?
Given that the sample of wight students predictions was
72    83    78    65    69    77    81    71
that I have calculated the sample standard deviation(s) = 6.2335, the sample mean = 74.5 and the sample size is 8.

In my own trial, 85% refers to z=1.440. The question requires my calculation base on t(20,0.075) but I cannot find the 0.075 in the table. So I doubt whether my directions aren't correct.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Your computations for sample mean and SD of the 8 observations are correct. Assuming that population $\sigma \approx 6.2336,$ you can express the margin of error $E = 2=z\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ where $z=1.4395$ cuts prob $0.075$ from upper tail of std normal and $\sigma$ is as estimated from your pilot sample. Solving, I get $n\approx 20.$ The value that cuts prob 0.075 from the upper tail of T(19) is about 1.5 instead of 1.4395. You could iterate to get $n \approx 22.$ But since you're basing the computation on rough est of $\sigma$ from a pilot study, you're only aiming for an aprx value of $n.$

Comment: Different printed tables of the t dist'n give various values. You might find a table that cuts 0.075 from T(19), but if not you could use software, or a statistical calculator, or an online procedure instead of printed t table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation. Yet, I have a doubt: where do you get the z = 1.4395? Thank you!

Comment: I used R, where `qnorm` is a normal quantile function (inverse CDF): code  `qnorm(1-.15/2)` returns  $1.439531.$ You can get 2-place accuracy directly from a printed standard normal CDF table and maybe an accurate 3rd place by interpolation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation!

Comment: See simulation in Answer format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simulation that serves as a 'reality check' on my answer in Comments that the necessary sample size
is around 20 or 22.

In R, the procedure `t.test` with parameter `conf.lev=.85)` will use data `x` show an 85% confidence interval for the population mean $\mu.$.

Suppose, for planning purposes, we use the sample mean and SD from your pilot
experiment with eight observations to be the population mean and SD.
Then we can simulate vector `x` of $n=22$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=74.5, \sigma=6.23).$ And use `t.test` to find the resulting 85% CI for $\mu.$ Finally, we can find the half-length of the CI to be the margin of error $E$ and see how close it is to $E = 2.$

```
set.seed(320)
x = rnorm(22, 74.5, 6.23)
CI = t.test(x, conf.lev = .85)$conf.int;  CI
[1] 73.21693 77.44468
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.85

me = diff(CI)/2;  me
[1] 2.113874
```

The result is a little larger than we hoped. But this is
only for one sample. If we do this for 10,000 samples and
average the results, we can get an idea whether $n = 22$
is, on average, sufficient to have a margin of error
of the desired size.

```
set.seed(2021)
me = replicate(10000, 
                diff(t.test(rnorm(21,14.5,6.24),
                 conf.lev=.85)$conf.int)/2)
mean(me)
[1] 1.969126

hdr = "Simulated Margins of Error for n = 21"
hist(me, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

[image]

So margins of error are often as small as 1.5 or as large as 2.3, but they are mostly near 2.0, as desired.